Audio jack bypass with volume control exhibits bad attenuation
I'm building an arcade cabinet and I have a computer as the source of the audio and a small powered amplifier for the speakers. I'm using a 3.5 mm headphone cable to connect the two. This is working just fine but I'd also like to have a volume control and headphone bypass in the loop, so if someone wanted to play games without bothering others, they could plug in headphones. Or just turn the volume of the machine down.
To that end, I have this very basic circuit:

and while it works (audio coming from the computer is heard in both the audio out jack as well as the bypass jack) the pot doesn't do much, except right at about 95% rotated, then it jumps to full volume. The tone of the sound is also pretty miserable until at that >95% point. Pot is 10 kΩ series A logarithmic.
Hooking this up to my scope, I found that if I don't have any headphones plugged into either output or bypass jacks, I see output I would expect (this is my computer playing a 100 Hz sine wave, both the computer and the pot at around 50%, both left and right channels)

but as soon as I plug headphones in:

I imagine my circuit is too simple and I'm missing some critical understanding on this signal should pass through. I'd love pointers on what I should be learning to understand why this is happening.

(: "powered amplifier" opposed to the best amplifier is a good speaker(/antenna)? :)

I have two speakers and a sub. Afraid I need something to power those. The amp is this guy, if anyone's curious. https://a.co/d/drAALYc

Your best option would be to use a separate headphone amp with its own volume control. That way you won't have to worry about the impedance of the headphones. This need not be an expensive option as headphone amp ICs are very cheap these days.

The potentiometers are being used incorrectly. Swap one with two and four with five and use maybe 100 ohm pot,  and while it won't be perfect it should be better than what you're getting.

Your headphones have an impedance of (typically) 8 to 32 Ω. You're feeding these through a 10 kΩ (10,000 Ω) so the attenuation is massive1 until you get close to fully clockwise. This is one reason why we don't use potentiometers directly on loud speaker circuits. (The other is the power dissipation in the potentiometer.)
If you want to keep things simple then try replacing with 100 Ω pots. Ideally these would be "audio taper" (logarithmic) type.
1 At mid-position you have 5 kΩ series resistance with your 25 Ω (keeping the maths simple) headphones. That's a 5k:25 = 200:1 attenuation. [Error fixed following correction in the comments.]
With a 100 Ω pot at mid-position you'd have 50:25 = 2:1 attenuation.
(Both the above calculations assume a linear pot for simplicity, but the idea should be clear.)

I don't have other logarithmic pots lying about, but I did have a 1K and 100ohm (single gang; so only one channel) and I found that both behave exactly the same when the headphones are plugged in. I tried different headphones (first were Beats with a TRRS plug, second were headphones with a TRS plug), same outcome.
I tried plugging the output into a small powered speaker with a headphone in jack and that seemed to work just fine.

Also, I think your math above is wrong? mid-position of a 10kΩ resistor would be 5K, not 50K? So the attenuation would be 200:1 (your point is still valid though).

Your "small powered speaker" probably has a very high input impedance, or at least much higher than headphones.

Assuming my understanding that "logarithmic" pots are two linear pots sellotaped together, I would argue that "audio taper" needs no quotes, but "logarithmic" does.

@AdamBarnes it depends. Good log pots use a variable deposited resistance medium to get a true logarithmic curve. Bad/cheap ones use two or more linear sections.

@user1937198 I'd love to know where to buy/which search terms to use to find the former.

@JohnRennie The amp's input is 21kΩ, so yeah... just a bit higher.

You are connecting the headphones like this:

where R is the resistance of the pot and I'll use H for the resistance of the headphones. We can redraw this as:

where the number x is 1 when the volume is turned to maximum and 0 when it's turned to minimum. The voltage on the headphones is then given by (assuming a linear pot for simplicity):
Vo = Vin R'/(R' + (1 - x)R
where R' is the parallel resistance of xR and H:
R' = xRH/(xR + H)
We can use this to calculate the voltage you get on 16 ohm headphones as you adjust the wiper, and for the 10k pot the voltage looks like this:

And you can see that the voltage only increases right at the end of the track. Even if we take the pot down to 100 ohms we still get:

So even with a 100 ohm pot you don't get half voltage until about 90% of the way through the track. This just isn't a good solution for low impedance headphones.
You could try using a variable resistance in series, but the problem is the volume will change if you use headphones with a different impedance so this isn't ideal either.
In audio amps the headphone output is normally taken from between the preamp and the power amp, but you don't have a separate preamp so this won't be possible. The best solution is probably to use a separate headphone amp. This won't be expensive as a basic headphone amp is about $5.

I disagree, this is very good with 100R. You are at 0.2, or -14dB at half rotation, That is a good approximation of actual log law, the blue line in Fig 4 here https://sound-au.com/pots.htm#chg-law - back in the days when I did analogue design, 10k with 1k6 to ground was a common volume control setup that I used.

@danmcb Try it and see how it sounds I guess.

I didn't with headphones directly, but I have used the high impedance version of this curve many times with good results. it is possible that the OPs cans are nothing like 16R at actual audio frequencies though.

Bah... I wired the 100Ω pot wrong (had ground to wiper, no idea why I did that). With it wired up correctly (output to wiper), I see very reasonable output with the 16Ω headphones plugged in.

I think I'll try adding a resistor to see if the 10k pot will work. If that doesn't fly, I'll move down to a 1k (smallest I can find that has the shaft length I need) and add a 150Ω resistor (which I think is right, given the "between 6:1 and 10:1 ratio" mentioned on sound-au.com.
Or just get a headphone amp.

As stated above, you need a much lower value pot. If you know the impedance of the headphones, you might just be lucky enough to be able to arrange things to get quasi-log law, using the headphone impedance to slug the pot law. (Good luck finding a 100 ohm stereo log law pot).
For instance, a 10k pot with a 1k6 load from wiper to ground gixes a decent approximation of log law. At centre position, you would be about 14dB down. Anything between about 12dB and 20dB at centre feels quite usable in my experience.
If you are dealing with headphones of really unknown impedance (32R up to 600R and more is possible) this approach is probably going to become impractical. If you want to stay with a passive solution, you could look for a dual rotary switch and use fixed resistors to give a few fixed volume levels. Otherwise, you are looking at using an active headphone amp.

The headphones I'm testing with are 16Ω (another pair are 32Ω, which explains why I couldn't ever hear anything out of them). But even with a 100Ω pot, I don't get a better response than I do with the 10K pot.
